# Appended text with keyup event disappears after button click jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Using jQuery, I' m downloading an image into SVG format.

Now, I wanted to show a title just above image. I tried to achieve this with keyup event. When I write the title, my script appends it into the div as it suppose to be but as soon as I click on download button, the title disappears and the image downloads without the appended title.

I wanted to download the image with title above that's actually an appended text.

html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">

      <label>Write Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="qr_frame_text"  id="qr_frame_text">

</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">

    <div  id="qr-container">
      <div id="get_frame_text"></div> //Here I'm appending the title

       <div id="img" class="qr-img">
          <img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode($image) !!}" class="img-fluid" />
       </div>

     </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    $("#qr_frame_text").keyup(function () {
         $("#get_frame_text").html(this.value);
    });


$( document ).ready(function() {
    domtoimage.toSvg(node)
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
var node = document.getElementById("qr-container");
    $('#qr2').click(function() {

     $('#qr-container').html("div id=\"get_frame_text\"></div>\n" +
       "<div id=\"img\" class=\"qr-img\">\n" +
    " <img src=\"data:image/png;base64, {!!base64_encode($image) !!}\" class=\"img-fluid\" />\n"+
    "</div>\n");

            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = 'qrcode.svg';
            link.href = dataUrl;
            link.click();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working code sample (with a fiddle/sandbox if possible)

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky
I'm using a dependency named tsayen/dom-to-image. It's just a piece of code out of my largest module so hard to provide fiddle. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `domtoimage.toSvg(node)` *after* you have done the following:

```
     $('#qr-container').html("div id=\"get_frame_text\"></div>\n" +
       "<div id=\"img\" class=\"qr-img\">\n" +
    " <img src=\"data:image/png;base64, {!!base64_encode($image) !!}\" class=\"img-fluid\" />\n"+
    "</div>\n");
```

Remember, `var node = document.getElementById("qr-container");` is not saving a snapshot of the node. It will change if it is modified.

You are changing the element to no longer contain the input before saving it. If you are trying to reset the changes, do that in your `.then()`.

Comment: That's awesome !. 
Now I can see the tile in my downloaded image. 
We are very close, just one step away. Now onclick, the text must stay there but it disappears. How can I keep the text showing above image even after downloading?

Comment: Why are you overwriting that element at all?

Comment: Sorry, what should I do ? I just edited my question to follow your steps, Advise me if I' m doing something wrong.

Comment: I cant answer your question. You are changing the HTML of the div `#qr-container` in this handler. I don't know why